# Parameterising values causes error in powershell/msbuild command

Tags: powershell, msbuild, powershell-5.0

I have a powershell script that in turn calls msbuild.exe and runs it with a solution value and a parameters argument. If i run this script by writing the line manually it runs as expected and builds the solution, however, due to the fact that this script is designed to build multiple solutions, the parameters, solution file path, and msbuild path are all passed as variables.

The line that i need to run looks like this:

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe' FooBar.sln "/t:rebuild" /p:PlatformTarget=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:CustomizablePublishDir=true /p:OutDir=F:\agent\_work\1\s\Deploy.Temp\Foo.Bar.Binaries\\ | Out-Host
```

And the way it is split into variables is as follows:

```
$1 = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
$2 = 'FooBar.sln'
$3 = "/t:rebuild /p:PlatformTarget=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:CustomizablePublishDir=true /p:OutDir=F:\agent\_work\1\s\Deploy.Temp\Foo.Bar.Binaries\\ | Out-Host"


& $1 $2 $3
```

For context, to get these values we use an XML with many nodes with 3 properties on each.

The error i get when i run the paramaterised script is as follows:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: The name "Foo_Bar:PlatformTarget=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:CustomizablePublishDir=true /p:OutDir=F:\agent\_work\1\s\Deploy.Temp\Foo.bar.Binaries\\ | Out-Host" contains 
an invalid character ".".
```

Obviously this is due to how powershell is handling the strings but I can't figure out how to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

`| Out-Host` should *not* be passed as part of an argument to an application - but that's not the issue here.

It seems to be a combination of combining all command line switches in a single string and having `.` anywhere in said argument - if I split the string into individual parts or replace your `OutDir` argument with a path that doesn't contain any `.`, `msbuild` proceeds to attempt to build the projects:

```
$msbuild = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\BuildTools\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe'
$solution = 'FooBar.sln'
$arguments = "/t:rebuild /p:PlatformTarget=AnyCPU /p:Configuration=Release /p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:CustomizablePublishDir=true /p:OutDir=F:\agent\_work\1\s\Deploy.Temp\Foo.Bar.Binaries"

&$msbuild $solution $arguments.Split(' ') |Out-Host
```

Comment: Can you explain why ```| Out-Host``` shouldn't be passed to an application? And why it works if it shouldn't? Using ```$argument.Split(' ')``` seems to have worked! Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Because `Out-Host` is a powershell cmdlet, not a valid argument to `msbuild`.